# How many Crawlers can run simultaneously using storm crawler

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am working on StormCrawler 1.10,archetype 1.11 and Elastic Search 6.4.x. How many crawlers can run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crawlers ==  topologies? As many as you want as long as they have different names. Why do you need multiple topologies? You can have a single one dealing with multiple sites

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added multiple urls in seeds file and I applied **FastURLFilter** something like `[   { "scope": "domain:abce.org",      "patterns": [ "AllowPath /ghi/","AllowPath /jkl/","AllowPath /mno/", "AllowPath /pqr/", "DenyPath .+" ] } ]`.The crawler is working fine. How can I filter the results by sites in elastic search. If suppose I want to search a keyword **test** on specific site **abce.org/mno** how can I achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you filter on the field host? 
https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/ES_IndexInit.sh#L132
+host:abcd.org +content:keyword

Comment: Host field in elastic search doesn't have any values. Is there any way that I can store the seed url in host fileld.